# Split specific strings in a vector using regex

Tags: regex, r, nlp, tokenize, strsplit

I have a vector of strings, some of which include punctuations/symbols. For example:

```
words <- ("hi", "my.", "name!", "is98", ""joe"")
```

My goal is to create a vector that has all these words, but the punctuations, numbers, and symbols are made into their own string in the vector. So in this case

```
("hi", "my", ".", "name", "!", "is", "98", """, "joe", """)
```

My initial plan was to use `grep` to identify the indices where said punctuations exist, then loop through them and use `strsplit` to divide them based on said punctuations, as follows:

```
puncIndex <- grep('[\\"!?.^]', words)
for(i in puncIndex){
  strsplit(words[i], '[\\"!?.^]')
}
```

But I'm having a couple of problems. One being that I realize that the result of `strsplit` is going to be a list itself, and I can't figure out how to cleanly just move each of the components back to the original vector. The other being that even when I try `strsplit` on just one word, it only returns the first part. For example:

```
strsplit(words[2], ".")
[[1]]
[1] "my"
```

EDIT: added numbers as a class to be separated as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split on the word boundary which exists at the middle.

```
words <- c("hi", "my.", "name!", "is", '"joe"')
unlist(strsplit(words, '(?<=.)\\b(?=.)', perl=TRUE))
#[1] "hi"   "my"   "."    "name" "!"    "is"   "\""   "joe" 
#[9] "\""
```

The trick here is `\\b` called word boundary which matches between a word char and non-word char (vice-versa). So this alone would match the start and the end if the starting and ending character is a word character. But using assertions, it ensures that there must be atleast one char exists before and after the word boundary.

**Update:**

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(words, '[A-Za-z]+|[^A-Za-z]+'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked as well! Is there a performance difference between using \b and using \w like the other proposed answer?

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased my question better. I meant more what the difference in output would be, given that I tried both and they both gave the same output. But reading your explanation again, I think I understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
  res <- unlist(strsplit(words, '(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)',
                   perl=TRUE))
  res
  #[1] "hi"   "my"   "."    "name" "!"    "is"   "\""   "joe"  "\""
```

Or using `str_extract_all`

```
 library(stringr)
 unlist(str_extract_all(words, '\\w+|\\W+'))
 #[1] "hi"   "my"   "."    "name" "!"    "is"   "\""   "joe"  "\""
```

EDIT: Added @Avinash Raj's suggestion

#### data

```
 words <- c("hi", "my.", "name!", "is", '"joe"')
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution worked perfect. One more question (apologies for forgetting to ask first): how would I alter it to separate numbers as well?

Comment: @NeonBlueHair Please update your post with a new example that has numbers as well